# SQL Query to Group address table with multiple entries of same client but with different address code

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Table with address details as below.
+Table View

```
-ClientID|Address Code|EMAIL

4566666|02|eeeee@gmail.com

4566666|03|77eee@gmail.com

1566656|01|HHHHH@gmail.com

1566656|02|JJJJJ@gmail.com

1566656|03|BBBBB@gmail.com
```

Expected Result:

```
ClientID|Address code 1|EMAIL 1| Address code 2| Email 2|Address code 3| Email 3|

4566666|02|eeeee@gmail.com|03|77eee@gmail.com

1566656|01|HHHHH@gmail.com|02|JJJJJ@gmail.com|03|BBBBB@gmail.com
```

Comment: I have to submit a report based on your response please update.

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as (
    select
        row_number() over(partition by "ClientID" order by "AddressCode") AS row_num,
        "ClientID",
        "AddressCode",
        "EMAIL"
    from Table1
)
select
    "ClientID",
    max(case when row_num = 1 then "AddressCode" end) as AddressCode1,
    max(case when row_num = 1 then "EMAIL" end) as Email1,
    max(case when row_num = 2 then "AddressCode" end) as AddressCode2,
    max(case when row_num = 2 then "EMAIL" end) as Email2,
    max(case when row_num = 3 then "AddressCode" end) as AddressCode3,
    max(case when row_num = 3 then "EMAIL" end) as Email3
from cte
group by "ClientID"
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85c46/13)

Comment: I am using SQL developer to run above query i get below error please advise. Error:ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 10

Comment: with ADDRESSES_TABLE as (select*,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ENTITY_ID order by ADDRESSCODE) as ROW_NUM from ADDRESSES_TABLE)
select entity_id,max(case when row_num = 1 then AddressCode end) as AddressCode1,max(case when row_num = 1 then Email end) as Email1,max(case when row_num = 2 then AddressCode end) as AddressCode2,max(case when row_num = 2 then Email end) as Email2,max(case when row_num = 3 then AddressCode end) as

Comment: @user2713588: So, you are using Oracle then. Please never forget to mention the SQL product you are using upfront.

Comment: @user2713588: Perhaps replacing the `*` in the CTE definition with `Table1.*` (or whatever table name you are using) will fix the issue in this case.

Comment: Sorry, Will mention the same next time for sure....

Comment: Hi Andriy, Could you please explain why cte is used.  I have all details in one table, Table name "Addresses_table", I am a beginner level in SQL.  Could you please modify above query with mentioned modification and share to suit running the same in SQL developer.

Comment: @user2713588 I've changed an answer, see updated and sql fiddle. CTE used only for numbering, you can use subquery, but I think cte is much more readable

Comment: Thanks Andriy,  I modified the query as advised.  It worked gave the output as expected.. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Thanks Roman and Andriy,  I got the output as expected.

Comment: @user2713588: Sorry, didn't see your question to response in time, glad things have eventually worked out well for you. A WITH expression (or a derived table of any kind at all for that matter) had to be used because with this method, rows needed to be enumerated (with ROW_NUMBER) *before* grouping. You would be unable to both use ROW_NUMBER *and* group the results at the same time the way it's done here. By the way, you can use the `@username` pattern, as I or Roman did (without formatting and at any position of your comment), to make sure the person you address gets notified of your message.